# how to remove extra whitespace surronding video in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am embedding a video in the page , but their is white space between Menu and video . as shown in pic . (NOTE: RED color means white space )

[image]

my code is as follows  : --

```css
 #media {
     margin-left: 0px;
     margin-right: 0px;
     background-color: red;
     padding-right: 3.5%;
     padding-left: 3.5%;
     padding-top: 0px;
 }
```

```html
<div id="media">
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <video autoplay loop class="embed-responsive-item">
            <source src="Media/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
</div>
```

how can I remove the extra white spacing .

thanks in advance ....

Comment: check the padding for the inner divs classes.

Comment: add display block to video tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your menu is within `<nav>` tag, for example, then you have to check that too.

That space is created because of 2 possible reasons:

1. Top padding/margin from your video container.
2. Bottom padding/margin from your menu container.

**Tip:**

1. Right click and inspect the menu
2. See where it's adding bottom padding or margin (usually you want to check `<ul>`, `<nav>` or `<div>` containing the menu code.
3. Edit the values until the output is the one that you like.
4. Copy those CSS styles to your .css file in your project and press F5.

A quick solution without knowing your code or having a plunkr available would be:

```
.nav#myMenu {
  padding-bottom: 0!important;
  margin-bottom: 0!important;
}

#video {
  padding-top: 0!important;
  margin-top: 0!important;
}
```

The `!important` statement after the CSS rule is used for overriding other styles that are higher priority like inline styles or rules that come after this one in your code.

Comment: your troubleshooting techniques really helped me ...thanks

Comment: @speedyraz I'm glad I could be of help! Good luck and have a nice day! :D